# Подключение dll, св-ва проекта

Tags: c++, dll

Подключаю dll к проекту в MSVS посредством LoadLibrary, т.е. во время вып. Вопрос: что мне надо указать в свойствах проекта? Надо ли указать .lib файл динамической библиотки в линковщике? Что еще? Надо ли указывать еще какие-то каталоги включения? И еще: мой LoadLibrary не хочет принимать строку типа "Example.dll", пишет про _wchar. Как исправить?

Вообще вопрос, если надо что-то указывать о dll в св-вах проекта, то как быть, если я хочу не перезапускать приложение, а его приостановить, обновить dll и перезагрузить только поставляемый этой dll функционал, что нормально делается с помощью GetProcessAddress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ничего не указывать в свойствах проекта для корректной работы через `LoadLibrary()` + `GetProcAddress()`. Может быть удобно добавить заголовки, описывающие функции и структуры данных из DLL, но не обязательно.

Проблема с "_wchar" решается путем явного использования `LoadLibraryA()`.